# Rails 4 ArgumentError in Controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a web application that allows users to add videos from youtube
but getting `ArgumentError in VideosController#create`:

> The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

videocontroller.rb

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController


    def index
    @videos = Video.order('Created_at DESC')
  end


  def new
    @video = Video.new
  end

  def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    if @video.save
        flash[:success] = 'Video Added!'
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(:link)
  end
end
```

videos.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  YT_LINK_FORMAT = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/i
  before_create -> do
    uid = link.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)

    self.uid = uid[2] if uid && uid[2]

    if self.uid.to_s.length != 11
      self.errors.add(:link, 'is invalid.')
      false
    elsif Video.where(uid: self.uid).any?
      self.errors.add(:link, 'is not unique.')
      false
    else
      get_additional_info
    end
  end

    validates :link, presence: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT

  private
```

Do i add `\A` and `\z` to the `YT_LINK_FORMAT` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `videos.rb` change the definition of `YT_LINK_FORMAT`:

```
YT_LINK_FORMAT = /\A.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*\z/i
```

(basically replacing your initial `^` with `\A`, and putting `\z` at the end)

`\A and \z` match the beginning and end of a string; `^ and $` match the beginning and end of a line.  Since you are not defining your regex as multiline you need to use the string matchers not the line ones.

It's what the error is trying to tell you; it's a bit better described in the API documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of